# Using mutable arrays in other classes

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I've tried several ways that i've found here but none have worked. what would be an easy way to pass this NSMutalbeArray into another View controller?

```
    NSMutableArray *pph = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [pph addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d     %d     %d",diario.Cowid,diario.Lact,diario.Del]];
```

on the same file below i have

```
- (IBAction)masInfoPPH;
{
    tipo = @"PPH";
    adiario = pph;
    NSLog(@"\n Array adiario: %@",pph);
    DetDiarioViewController *DetDiarios = [[DetDiarioViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:DetDiarios animated:YES];
}
```

for some reason pph (the NSMutalbeArray) gets here as null but up there it does give me the objects it should have. adiario is a global array or at least its supposed to be. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really are no global arrays.  Create a property in your class for pph in the interface of your class.

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *pph;  



self.pph = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.pph addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d     %d     %d",diario.Cowid,diario.Lact,diario.Del]]
```

But you still need to get that into next view controller.  Create a similar property in it's interface and then set it before pushing

```
DetDiarioViewController *detDiarios = [[DetDiarioViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
detDiarios.pph = self.pph;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detDiarios animated:YES];
```

BTW - in objective-c the convention is to use a lowercase letter for the first letter of an instance

Answer (score 0):

The scope of your `pph` array is unclear from your description..  But ANYTHING declared inside a single method is LOCAL to that method, unless it is *returned* BY that method.

You have several options... Declare the array as an instance variable, ie..

```
@interface YourClass: NSObject {  NSMutableArray *pph; }
```

or

```
@implementation YourClass {  NSMutableArray *pph; }
```

or as a `static` variable (in your `.m` file) (which would enable you to access the value from `Class` (`+`) methods..

`static  NSMutableArray *pph = nil;`

or most preferably... as a property

```
@interface YourClass @property (strong) NSMutableArray *pph;
```

which you can then call upon from any instance method via the automatically synthesized Ivar `_pph`, or via the property's accessors.. `self.pph`.

Hope this helps!